# SQL performance based on the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I am trying to reuse a query, instead of creating several scenarios. Basically I am getting a COUNT from a big table.

The question is: am I going to lose performance on the long run if I am using

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [Documents] WHERE UploadDate > '1900/1/1' AND UploadDate < GETDATE()
```

Instead of a simple

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [Documents]
```

Basically the 2 queries would return the same thing, because I want to return ALL the records in this case. But under some other circumstances, the date pair will use different parameters.

Comment: If you have an index on that column it should not matter

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Possibly. As long as there exists a clustered index (and primary key) the simple (2nd) query is preferred and will be as fast as it could get. By adding where clause(s) you **could** decrease the performance but it depends on the presence of any index(es) on the columns being filtered as well as the data contained in that column.

Comment: @Igor What about just replacing `COUNT(id)` with `COUNT(1)`? Assuming that the `ID` column is a Primary Key or identity column, which kind of sounds like it is from its name. If there would be a index on `UploadDate` there wouldn't be a need to access table or row data pages, so no lookups or clustered index scans necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the count based on some parameters, I do not think there will a significant difference, if you have an index defined on `UploadDate`. If you are using a stored procedure, it might look like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCount
(
   @FromDate DATETIME2 = '1900-01-01',
   @ToDate DATETIME2 = '9999-12-31',
   -- other filters may come here
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(id) 
   FROM [Documents] 
   WHERE UploadDate > @FromDate AND @ToDate < @ToDate
END
GO

-- get all
EXEC dbo.GetCount
-- get from date
EXEC dbo.GetCount @FromDate = '2015-03-01'
-- to date
EXEC dbo.GetCount @ToDate = '2016-03-01'
-- both
EXEC dbo.GetCount @FromDate = '2015-03-01', @ToDate = '2016-03-01'
```

You can also try to obtain the minimum SQL to run, by **creating a dynamic SQL**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCount
(
   @FromDate DATETIME2 = NULL,
   @ToDate DATETIME2 = NULL
   -- other filters may come here
)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'
       SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [Documents]
       WHERE 1 = 1 
   '
   IF (@FromDate IS NOT NULL) @SQL = @SQL + ' UploadDate > @FromDate'
   IF (@ToDate IS NOT NULL) @SQL = @SQL + ' UploadDate > @ToDate'

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, '@FromDate DATETIME2, @ToDate DATETIME2', @FromDate, @ToDate
END
```

This offers the flexibility of open interval to the left and/or right.

If you are **dynamically generating queries from the application layer** (e.g. LINQ2SQL), the best option is generate it based on your parameters. This will lead to the shortest and fastest queries:

```
var query = DbContext.Documents;
if (fromDate.HasValue) query = query.Where(UploadDate > fromDate.Value);
if (toDate.HasValue) query = query.Where(UploadDate < toDate.Value);
int count = query.Count();
```

The last two solutions also allow to easily add new filters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count *everything* and then things that meet a condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total_cnt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN UploadDate > '1900-01-01' AND UploadDate < GETDATE()
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as specific_cnt
FROM [Documents] d;
```

Comment: That does not really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about varying performance based on the range values you specify in your query, because of parameter sniffing, then you can add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end of your query.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM [Documents] 
WHERE UploadDate > '1900/1/1' AND UploadDate < GETDATE()
OPTION (RECOMIPLE)
```

This will make sure that your newly generated plan is the best possible that the Optimizer could come up with, at that moment, on its own, for that date range, if you decide to check starting from `'2011/1/1'` for example.